# Set Datetimepicker minDate based on another Datetimepicker date

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am using **Datetimepicker** with date only format on both classes(It is working fine if I select Date from the **ValidFrom** Box). My use case was that once **ValidFrom** is selected, the **ValidTo** should automatically **increase** by 1 month(this is happening). Now the problem I am facing is that once, the date from **ValidFrom** is selected in **ValidTo** Box the date should not be less than the date in **ValidFrom** and also, date in **ValidTo** can only be decreased and should not increase 30 days.

Following is my code for Datetimepicker:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ValidFrom').datetimepicker({
            datepicker: true,
            timepicker: false,
            format: 'm/d/Y',
            step: 30,
            minDate: new Date(),
            onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
                var date = new Date($input.val());
                date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
                date = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
                $('#ValidTo').val(date);
            },

        });
        $('#ValidTo').datetimepicker({
            datepicker: true,
            timepicker: false,
            format: 'm/d/Y',
            step: 30,
            minDate: new Date(),

        });

    });

</script>
```

P.S. I've already tried the ways mentioned in other question, but they were not fruitful.

Comment: What other question?

Answer (score 0):

Try with updating `minDate` and `maxDate` as below.

```
$('#ValidTo').datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
$('#ValidTo').datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', maxDate);
```

Or if it doesn't work then try like below.

```
$('#ValidTo').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(minDate);
$('#ValidTo').data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(maxDate);
```

Your complete code should be like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ValidFrom').datetimepicker({
    datepicker: true,
    timepicker: false,
    format: 'm/d/Y',
    step: 30,
    minDate: new Date(),
    onChangeDateTime: function(dp, $input) {
      var date = new Date($input.val());
      $('#ValidTo').datetimepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
      date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
      $('#ValidTo').datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);
      date = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
      $('#ValidTo').val(date);
    },
  });
  
  $('#ValidTo').datetimepicker({
    datepicker: true,
    timepicker: false,
    format: 'm/d/Y',
    step: 30,
    minDate: new Date(),
  });

});
```

Comment: It shows this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: minDate is not defined`

Comment: `minDate` is your date object which you have to pass. I've just wrote there for example.

Comment: I am absolutely new to this concept. Could you help me how to pass this date object in minDate?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [handy tool](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) that might help create the constraints you want.